# Playing audio on button click (No loop)

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, onclick

I have 64 buttons, all with an individual audio file. Half of them I want to loop the audio when clicked, the others to just play the file once. Currently my code forces all to loop, so I am needing help to find a solution so that some loop, and some don't.

(I have edited the example to show only 3 buttons, I want Button 3 (FX) to only play once per click).

**JS:**

```
var audio = [];
var isPlaying = [];

function sound(id){
  if(isPlaying[id]){
    audio[id].pause();
    isPlaying[id] = false;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    audio[id].play();
    isPlaying[id] = true;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function createAudio(src,i){
  audio[i] = new Audio();
  audio[i].src = src;
  audio[i].loop = true;
  isPlaying[i] = false;
}

var mySources = ['audio/drums/1.wav','audio/bass/2.wav','audio/fx/3.wav'];
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(1);"/>
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(2);"/>
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(3);"/>
```

I understand that currently all 3 buttons are linked to the sound function which is set to loop, however im unaware how to create another function without the loop, as the loop is stated within `createAudio` and with this being code from elsewhere, i'm unsure on how that works.

Comment: Hi, it's you again with the similar question. Can you show how do you call your `creaetAudio()` function? I think it can be done within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set whether a sound is a loop in the same function as you play it, instead of when it is created. This would also allow you to sometimes loop a certain sound and sometimes play it just once, instead of always having it be the same kind.

#### JS:

```
function sound(id, loop){
  audio[id].loop = loop;
  /* ... */
}

function createAudio(src,i){
  audio[i] = new Audio();
  audio[i].src = src;
  isPlaying[i] = false;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(1, true);"/>
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(2, false);"/>
<img class="button" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(3, true);"/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for your help! (However instead of true/false I just created a new function, and I did have to change it to `audio[id].loop = true;`)